# Unable to import cufflinks in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm having an issue importing cufflinks inside Jupiter notebook. 
I've used 
`pip install cufflinks`, 
`pip install cufflinks==0.8.2`, `conda install cufflinks`, `conda install -c bioconda cufflinks`, etc. and other commands I've found on this site and elsewhere.

When I attempt to import in Jupyter on localhost I get

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-d18380adf441> in <module>()
      6 import plotly.graph_objs as go
      7 import plotly.figure_factory as ff
----> 8 import cufflinks as cf
      9 cf.set_config_file(offline=True, world_readable=True, theme='ggplot')

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cufflinks'
```

I'm not sure what else can be done, so as to resolve this error.

Comment: Please describe how you are trying to install with pip. Using `!` ipynb magic? Installing to system python before you launch Jupyter notebook?

Comment: Please also share the output of pip install